# Android binding JAR: class-parse argumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: java, android, binding, jna

I created a Android Binding project under VS2019, to bind the jna-4.5.1.jar file which can be downloaded here http://www.java2s.com/example/jar/j/download-jna451jar-file.html.
I can send the test project if some wants to test directly.

I set the JAR build action to embedded jar, and I got a warning while compiling the project which I do not understand :
[image]

Why does it try to load a jar libjnidispatch.jnilib because it is incorporated in the jna-4.5.1.jar file? And does anyone know how I can correct this warning?
Do you think I should download the libjnidispatch.jnilib file and add it to the JAR folder and set it to EmbededNativeLibrary?

Thank you very much

Comment: The native code library is a JNI stub is needed for JNA to do its work and needs to be installed on your system. You can pre-install the jnilib and tell your app where it is to avoid having JNA try to extract it.   Also, 4.5.1 is many years old. Any reason not to use the current 5.8.0 version?

Comment: Hi @Daniel Widdis. Thanks for your response. Do you know where I can found the jni lib and how to install it, and how do you tell the app where it is? In fact, at the origin, I tried to bind another library autoreplyprint.aar for a printer, and within the .aar file I saw within the lib folder nzio.jar and jna-4.5.1.jar. I initially created a binding library with the autoreplyprint.aar as libraryprojectzip, and the two jar files (jna-4.5.1.jar and nzio.jar) as embeddedreferencejar, But I add lot of errors regarding jna libwhile building. So I decided to bind the jna jar file alone. Thank

Comment: And by the way the jnilibdispatch.so file are already present withi  the jna-4.5.1.jar file. Why doesn't it extract from the aar file itself. Sorry for asking so many questions but I am quite lost with android jar and dependencies. Thank

Comment: Not familiar with android / aar or detailed mechanics of extracting internal components, thus a comment offering suggestions rather than an answer.  You can find the jnidispatch files by extracting the jars in the `lib/native` subdirectory at JNA project on github: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native

Comment: As far as telling your app where to find it, the [javadocs for the Native class](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.8.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html) describe this in great detail at the top of the class with more detail here:  http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.8.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#library_search_paths